# Quoting in CSV from Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a project where I need to manipulate certain text files and write down as text files again. A sample file will look like
[image]

As you can see I have headers which are like `"A"`. When I use the following code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Test doc.txt",sep =";")
df.to_csv("Output.txt",sep=";",index = None)
```

I get the output as [image]

Now the headers are like `A`, the `"` are gone. How do I write the file in the exact same format as before? 
I also tried

```
df.to_csv("Output.txt",sep=";",index = None, header = ["'A'","'B'","'C'"])
```

But this gives me [image]
Now the header is `'A'` but still not in the original format.

If I try

```
df.to_csv("Output.txt",sep=";",index = None, header = ['"A"','"B"','"C"'])
```

Now it looks like [image]

Comment: use '"A"' ,
i.e. same as your last example but use single quotes outside and double quotes inside

Comment: Posting screen shots of text is supremely annoying. Please [edit] your question to supply the output as actual text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the default quote char.

```
df.to_csv("Output.txt", sep=';', index=None, quotechar="'", header=['"A"','"B"','"C"'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

df.to_csv("Output.txt",sep=";", index=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Comment: @DebdiptaMajumdar did you forget the `import csv`?

Comment: If I use this, even  the data for the 1st column is coming in {"}. I dont want that. I only need the headers to come in {"}